# ORDER BY FIELD with a wilcard?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have a field that can contain some prefixed strings:

```
word1
bla2
ttt3
word4 
[...]
```

I need to order SQL with for example `ttt3` first and then all other string after.
I tried this with no luck

```
ORDER BY FIELD (myField,'ttt3',*)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `ORDER BY CASE` construct.  It forces a 0 for the value you want to extract, and 1 for everything else, so the 0 sorts first.  It just fits into the `ORDER BY` list like any column, comma-separated, so you can add additional sort columns afterward.

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN myField = 'ttt3' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  myField,
  other_order_col,
  other_order_col2
```

Comment: I'd choose `order by case when myfield = 'ttt3' then 0 else 1 end, myfield` so that the ordering withing `else 1` fields is also by `myfield`

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY myField = 'ttt3' DESC
```

or more generic and vendor-independent:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN myField = 'ttt3' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```